# KEXT not loadable even System Integrity Protection is disable in 10.11

Tags: macos, kernel-extension

Currently I'm developing a small KEXT that can block access to the USB storage. However when I can't load my KEXT using kextutil

```
Code Signing Failure: not code signed
```

I did turn off the SIP in 10.11

```
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
```

Please help. I don't know what to do!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was long research I have did for these simple steps and documentation and I am listing it here for someone like me.

> Before following the procedure please disable SIP

**start your Mac in recovery mode by shutting it down and starting it by pressing command+R button until apple logo comes up.
open terminal application and enter below command**

1. csrutil disable
2. reboot

These are the important command for coping kext using root access to the location, changing its ownership to wheel, checking its dependancies of osbundlelibraries and checking if the kext is loadable or not.

**sudo cp -R**

**sudo chown -R root:wheel**

**sudo kextlibs -xml  //checks the osbundlelibrary files to be present in info plist**

**sudo kextutil -n -t  // check the kext and logs if the kext loadable or not**

**sudo kextutil -n  // check the kext and logs if the kext loadable or not**

**sudo kextutil  // check the kext and logs if the kext loadable or not**

**sudo kextload  // loads your kext if kernel doesn’t generate panic**

**sudo kextunload  // unloads your kext**

> Important urls

https://people.sissa.it/~inno/pubs/skb-reduced.pdf

https://github.com/objective-see/LuLu

https://objective-see.com/blog/blog_0x0B.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptIntro/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000191-SW1

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/boundaries/boundaries.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/NKEConceptual/intro/intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001858-CH225-SW1

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Features/Features.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000012-TPXREF101

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_Intro/AH_Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000376

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/WritingDeviceDriver/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000694

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/navigation/index.html#section=Technologies&topic=Kernel

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/NetworkDriver/2_IONetworkingFamily/IONetworkingFamily.html

http://dbmanagement.info/Books/MIX/OS_X_and_iOS_Kernel_Programming.pdf

https://www.fortinet.com/blog/threat-research/monitoring-macos--part-iii--monitoring-network-activities-using-.html

https://fortiguard.com/events/2270/learn-how-to-build-your-own-utility-to-monitor-malicious-behaviors-of-malware-on-macOS

https://github.com/slavaim/MacOSX-Network-Sockets-Filter

http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/howto/kext_tutorials/hello_kext/hello_kext.html

https://www.blackhat.com/us-18/presenters/Yu-Wang.html

**kernel control/event api usage**

https://www.synack.com/2015/12/13/monitoring-process-creation-via-the-kernel-part-iii/

**Best working model**

https://github.com/LawlietRyuzakiCode/NKETest

http://hitcon.org/2013/download/[B1]%20Pedro_HiTCON%202013%20Presentation_v2.pdf

https://github.com/changpingc/kernet

IMP Packet Creation Source
[enderunix Packet Creation Source](http://www.enderunix.org/docs/en/rawipspoof/)

```
https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/tree/master/Examples/GCD
https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services?language=objc
http://openssl.cs.utah.edu/docs/apps/x509v3_config.html
https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-howmitmproxyworks/
http://technologeeks.com/course.jl?course=OSXRE
https://www.fastcompany.com/3042030/the-huge-web-security-loophole-that-most-people-dont-know-about-and-how-its-be
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589622/how-does-a-root-ca-verify-a-signature
https://deliciousbrains.com/https-locally-without-browser-privacy-errors/
https://rednaga.io/2017/04/09/remote_kext_debugging/
http://www.robertopasini.com/index.php/2-uncategorised/628-osx-packaging-a-kernel-extension-for-distribution-and-installation
http://ddeville.me/2015/08/using-the-vmware-fusion-gdb-stub-for-kernel-debugging-with-lldb
https://objective-see.com/blog.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptDebugger/debug_tutorial.html
https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/turn-off-verbose-bootup.1247361/
https://adimitrov.net/main/code/code/raw_packet.c
http://www.enderunix.org/docs/en/rawipspoof/
https://www.eit.lth.se/ppplab/IPHeader.htm#TOS,%20Type%20of%20Service
https://www.tenouk.com/download/pdf/Module39.pdf
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000018-BAJFFJAD
https://github.com/slavaim/MacOSX-Network-Sockets-Filter
https://www.blackhat.com/us-18/arsenal.html#learn-how-to-build-your-own-utility-to-monitor-malicious-behaviors-of-malware-on-macos
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension?language=objc
https://github.com/TrustRouter/TrustRouter/blob/master/client/kernelmode/MacOS/trustrouter/trustrouter.c
https://github.com/LawlietRyuzakiCode/NKETest/blob/master/TestFilter/TestFilter/TestFilter.c
https://objective-see.com/blog/blog_0x0B.html
http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/
https://people.sissa.it/~inno/pubs/skb-reduced.pdf
http://haifux.org/lectures/122/FreeBSD_kernel_networking.pdf
http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch15/
```

**alternate packet forward and check**

sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P

netstat -a -n

sudo pfctl -s nat

sudo pfctl -F all -f /etc/pf.conf

echo "
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8443
" | sudo pfctl -ef -

nettop

sudo tcpdump -i en0 -p -vv -A ip and host 192.168.1.92

sudo tcpdump -i en0 -p -vv -A ip

sudo tcpdump -i en0 -p -vv -A ip and net 192.0.2.0/24