# Do we need to create any certificate to call https web service in Android

Tags: android, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Hi I am working on android application where I am using `https` protocol in all the web service. so to communicate with `https` enabled server from android app do we need to add any certificate in my `raw` folder of android ?

If yes then what is the process of it. I checked many answers but people are simply ignoring the https procotol just accepting all certificates or by pass.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you talking about access tokens?

Comment: No. I am talking for the ssl certificates *.cert files

Answer (score 1):

1. Create BouncyCastle `KeyStore`, put your certificate in it (you can use openssl), later put created `KeyStore` into res/raw folder.

In app:

1. Load your keystore file into java `KeyStore`
2. Feed your `HttpClient` with your `KeyStore`

Example:

```
// Load CAs from an InputStream
// (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
// From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("load-der.crt"));
Certificate ca;
try {
    ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
} finally {
    caInput.close();
}

// Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

// Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

// Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

// Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
URL url = new URL("https://certs.cac.washington.edu/CAtest/");
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
    (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
copyInputStreamToOutputStream(in, System.out);
```

source:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html

Comment: Do I have to use same generated KeyStore certificate to server also ?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking

Comment: I am asking for this process we have to keep certificate file either in `raw` or `assests` of android project so to make https connection with server do we have to keep same certificate file to server also which we have in android ?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188266/how-are-ssl-certificates-verified, the only difference is that you (application, which acts as web browser in that link) don't download certificate - you provide it with your application.

Comment: so according to that answer it means that you don't have to create any certificate & no need to add in android client also but you told this `Create BouncyCastle KeyStore, put your certificate in it (you can use openssl), later put created KeyStore into res/raw folder.`. now I am confused :(

Comment: Case in link describes how web browser works. Android has it's own CA (certificate authority) store. If your server certificate is not signed by one of certificate authority, you will have to tell android android to trust it (create `TrustStore` from `KeyStore` as described above).

Comment: alright so in case of server certificate is signed by one the certificate authority then in this case i don't have to create any certificate again & add it to raw folder. please confirm

Comment: please confirm about my above question & lets close it then i will accept it sure