# How the browser verifies that the web server's certificate was signed by the trusted certificate authority?

Tags: ssl

I wonder if anyone can provide more detailed description of point 2 of the answer to [How are ssl certificates verified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188266/how-are-ssl-certificates-verified).

What algorithms are used to verify that the certificate was signed by the trusted CA? What ideas are they based on? Why it is not possible to simulate trusted CA signature (make a certificate that the browser will treat as valid)?

Answer (score 0):

It's a digital signature. You can verify it via the public key in the associated certificate. The algorithms are as specified in the certificate itself.

Comment: too general answer